# RemoteWebDriver with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

I'm getting an error with connecting to my remote node and launching chrome via selenium.
My procedure:

- start hub
- start node with this bat:

> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar -role node -hub
>   http://"hubadress":4444/register/grid 
>   -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\Users\me\Downloads\chromedriver.exe"

then I run this code:

```
DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

Webdriver x = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://'localhost':444/wd/hub"),dc);
```

which yields result: ...Path to driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property.

I HAVE ALSO TRIED:

- starting chromedriver on node
- changing the localhost URL parameter in REMOTEWEBDRIVER to the adress of the node at port 9515 (port used for chromedriver)

Thank you so much for your time guys, I'm going insane and I need to troubleshoot some problems with firefox which works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that for two possible reasons.

#### Reason 1

Your `C:\Users\me\Downloads\chromedriver.exe` does not exist. Make sure that THAT is the path.

#### Reason 2

The double quotes around the path *might* be exacerbating it.  Take out the quotes to make it: `-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=c:\users\me\downloads\chromedriver.exe`

Other than that, everything you have there is just fine.  Make sure to address both of these reasons, and you should be golden.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add "/wd/hub" to the url when using RemoteWebDriver

Also, I don't think that the sigle quote in you url  is needed either:
http://'localhost':444/wd/hub

Answer (score 0):

Oh god. The slashes were the wrong way.

Should have been:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar -role node -hub
http://"hubadress":4444/register/grid  
Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:/Users/me/Downloads/chromedriver.exe"
```